# NSString constants for NSURLRequest HTTPMethod property?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, nsurlrequest

Does Foundation have NSString constants for the supported HTTPMethod values (eg for GET, POST, etc)?

Searched the NSURLRequest docs, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, `NSURLRequest` doesn't have any constants for HTTP method types. You could, however, define your own and use them elsewhere. Something like this:

```
//Somewhere
#define setPOST(request) [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"]

//...later in code
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
setPOST(request);
```

I would also highly recommend using [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). With that library, you can easily do things like:

```
[connectionMgr POST:url parameters:submitDict success:nil failure:nil]; //Obviously bare-bones, you'd need to fill in the parameters and blocks
```